# Shouldn't conda activate <env> ensure that default python, pip ect are changed to miniconda3/envs/<env>/bin?

Tags: python, bash, miniconda, virtual-environment

I am only somewhat familiar with conda. I kept having issues when trying to import modules in python, and then realised the python used by default in my active environment isn't the python in `~/miniconda3/envs/<env>`, but the python found in my `~/bin/` directory.

From what I gather, the default python/pip/pip3 ect. get decided by the `.bash_profile`:

`PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin`

Is there a way to change the `.bash_profile` so that the default is my environment bin without hardcoding it to use the environment name (ie, the path changes depending on which environment you activate?)

EDIT: So some answers indicate their may be something specifically wrong in my setup. Here is my `.bashrc`:

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# Uncomment the following line if you don't like systemctl's auto-paging feature:
# export SYSTEMD_PAGER=

# User specific aliases and functions
alias pip=~/bin/pip3.8 
alias python=~/bin/python3.8
export PATH=/home/USERNAME/bin/:/usr/bin/:$PATH

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/USERNAME/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/USERNAME/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/USERNAME/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/USERNAME/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

. "$HOME/.cargo/env"

export LC_CTYPE=C
```

and here is my `.bash_profile`:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin

export PATH
. "$HOME/.cargo/env"
```

Comment: If you have activated the environment using `conda activate <envname>`, `python` should point to the version of python installed in that environment, provided you have one. For `pip`, you should have it installed in the current environment, otherwise it will point to the system `pip`. When you installed `conda`, it might have added some lines to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`. Try restarting and activating the profile again, and check the outputs of `conda activate <envname>`, `which python`, `which pip`.

Comment: You are right, this should work exactly as you expect. What exactly did you do to get a different result?

Comment: I only started using conda/pip/python in the past 3 years, mostly using R, and through the mess of getting packages to work, I may have changed something I really shouldn't have. Would this be a `.bashrc` or a `.bash_profile` issue? I will add the contents of both as edits to my original question just in case.